# I want to create a carousel that looks like app store app carousel, I tried staggered grid layout but couldnt add padding to items

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I want to create a recyler view that looks like the carousel in iOS app store, I tried multiple things but all in vain,
Tried this lib https://github.com/frontierdotxyz/InfiniteScrollRecyclerView
but even with this lib what i get is a grid layout with carousel not the one i intend, sharing video for more context[image]
Here its kinda grid view but items in second row are not vertically aligned, Adding padding doesnt helps as the item on top in that column would also expand, Any help in this regard is appreciated

Comment: So i found a solution, Its the item decorator doing the job

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution by playing with the item decorator, posting it here to help others, you can play with the paddings to your desires:

```
public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private final int mSpace;

    public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
       this.mSpace = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(@NonNull Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
         outRect.top = mSpace;
         outRect.right = mSpace;
         outRect.bottom = mSpace;

         int position = ((RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).getViewPosition();
         if (position % 2 == 1) {
           outRect.left = -64;
           outRect.right = 80;
         }
     }
}
```